# resolv.conf and sporadic slow host resolving (DNS issue) - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, dns, resolv.conf

since last autumn I'm struggeling to find what's wrong with my network configuration on Ubuntustudio 20.04 which is basically a Ubuntu 20.04.

I installed from scratch last autumn with the official Ubuntustudio 20.04 iso.

The strange thing is that my `resolv.conf` links to `../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`

```
    /etc/resolv.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Sep 27 22:10 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
```

However, in the point release version 20.04.1 it obviously points to `../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf`.

The content in  `../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf` is

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
search fritz.box
```

I'm having another resolv.conf file in `/run/systemd/resolve` with exactly the same content.
The time stamps of both files are different though: The file in `../run/resolvconf` has the time stamp of the time when I switched on my machine. The file in `/run/systemd/resolve/` has a time stamp which is 30 min old.

In the folder `/run/systemd/resolve/`  there's also a `stub-resolv.conf` file with content:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search fritz.box
```

Does this all make sense and can somebody clearify this? Could this be the cause of my DNS issues?
Very sporadically the DNS lookup in Firefox takes 5 s or more. This happens about 20 time per day or more, but not always. When I tell Firefox to use DNS over HTTPS all is fine.

When I use dig in the terminal this also works most of the time, but sometimes there's a delay of several setting until I get any output. The DNS lookup times in this case are however also short on the order of 20 ms.

For instance this took ~10 s until I got the first output

```
traceroute facebook.com
traceroute to facebook.com (69.171.250.35), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  fritz.box (192.168.178.1)  9.270 ms  9.211 ms  9.272 ms
 2  loopback1.0002.acln.01.off.de.net.telefonica.de (62.52.200.219)  47.276 ms  47.403 ms  47.400 ms
 3  bundle-ether12.0001.dbrx.01.off.de.net.telefonica.de (62.53.12.0)  24.104 ms  24.351 ms  27.042 ms
 4  ae3-0.0001.corx.01.off.de.net.telefonica.de (62.53.28.154)  31.595 ms  36.469 ms  36.011 ms
 5  ae10-0.0001.corx.06.ham.de.net.telefonica.de (62.53.0.48)  33.152 ms ae4-0.0002.corx.02.ber.de.net.telefonica.de (62.53.0.72)  36.903 ms ae10-0.0001.corx.06.ham.de.net.telefonica.de (62.53.0.48)  35.555 ms
 6  bundle-ether1.0006.dbrx.01.ham.de.net.telefonica.de (62.53.14.27)  35.957 ms ae1-0.0002.dbrx.01.dus.de.net.telefonica.de (62.53.16.36)  24.730 ms bundle-ether2.0005.dbrx.01.ham.de.net.telefonica.de (62.53.14.231)  26.659 ms
 7  ae0-0.0002.prrx.01.ham.de.net.telefonica.de (62.53.6.109)  26.043 ms ae1-0.0002.prrx.01.ham.de.net.telefonica.de (62.53.6.207)  26.547 ms  27.471 ms
 8  ae0.pr02.ham3.tfbnw.net (157.240.72.132)  25.267 ms  25.832 ms  26.783 ms
 9  po102.psw04.ham3.tfbnw.net (74.119.78.17)  26.633 ms po102.psw03.ham3.tfbnw.net (74.119.78.5)  26.436 ms po102.psw01.dus1.tfbnw.net (157.240.35.105)  23.561 ms
10  157.240.38.185 (157.240.38.185)  23.765 ms 157.240.38.73 (157.240.38.73)  25.523 ms 173.252.67.59 (173.252.67.59)  25.862 ms
11  edge-star-mini-shv-01-any2.facebook.com (69.171.250.35)  24.973 ms  26.343 ms  24.574 ms

systemd-resolve --status
Global
       LLMNR setting: no                  
MulticastDNS setting: no                  
  DNSOverTLS setting: no                  
      DNSSEC setting: no                  
    DNSSEC supported: no                  
          DNS Domain: fritz.box           
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa     
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      corp                
                      d.f.ip6.arpa        
                      home                
                      internal            
                      intranet            
                      lan                 
                      local               
                      private             
                      test                

Link 2 (enp2s0)
      Current Scopes: DNS          
DefaultRoute setting: yes          
       LLMNR setting: yes          
MulticastDNS setting: no           
  DNSOverTLS setting: no           
      DNSSEC setting: no           
    DNSSEC supported: no           
  Current DNS Server: 192.168.178.1
         DNS Servers: 192.168.178.1
          DNS Domain: ~.           
                      fritz.box
```

One more info maybe: I was using a WLAN stick for roughly one week and didn't have such issues. Long DNS times occured only with LAN:

```
Network:   Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet driver: r8169 
           IF: enp2s0 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: d8:cb:8a:e8:e9:99
```

Comment: Do you have ```dnscrypt-proxy``` package installed? If so, Do you ***NEED*** it? I seem to recall having issues similar in that past while using it. It seemed ,to me, not worth the trouble anymore and found better alternatives.

Comment: Hi, no it's not installed. I think installing new that at least the symlink is correct.